# How to check 2 match values in multidimensional array in php

Tags: php

Here i will pass to values into multidimensional array, suppose any one of the value match means return `Match Found` else return `Match Not found` , i have tried but it is not working, how we can achieve this ?

> Updated code

```
    $questionResult = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            "result" => "pass",
            "mode" => "N-number of mode will come"
        ),

   1 => Array
        (
            "result" => "fail",
            "mode" => "Learn"
        )


);
$totalRecords = count($questionResult) ;
$Challenge = array("Challenge");
$questionFailSkip = array("fail", "skip");
$correctAnswer = array("pass");
if(in_array_userDefined($Challenge , $questionResult) && in_array_userDefined($questionFailSkip , $questionResult) && $totalRecords == 1){
    // $questionResult array present in "mode" => "Challenge" & $totalRecords == 1
    $resultData['showAnswer'] = FALSE;
}else if (in_array_userDefined($Challenge , $questionResult) && $totalRecords >= 2){
   // $questionResult array present in "mode" => "Challenge" & $totalRecords >= 2
 $resultData['showAnswer'] = TRUE;
}else if (){
// here i want to check mode != 'Challenge'& $totalRecords >= 2 how to write the condition
}else{
    $resultData['showAnswer'] = "Match Not Found" ;
}


echo "<pre>";
var_dump($resultData);

function in_array_userDefined($item , $array){
    $data = json_encode($array);
    foreach ( $item as $regex ) {
        if (preg_match('/"'.preg_quote($regex, '/').'"/i' , $data))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Before else condition i want to check mode != 'Challenge'& $totalRecords >= 2 how to write the condition**

Comment: why don't you use `in_array()` ?

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi, in_array it will support my case

Comment: Please don't change the question after people have answered it, it wastes other peoples time.  If you have a specific problem, this should have been in your question the first time!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to doubly iterate the array of associate arrays, checking all keys and values of each pair for a possible match:

```
$match_found = false;  
for ($i=0; $i < count($questionResult)-1; $i++) {
    for ($j=1; $j < count($questionResult); $j++) {
        foreach ($questionResult[$i] as $key=>$value) {
            if ($questionResult[$j][$key] == $value) {
                $match_found = true;
                break 3;     // if match found, break out of all 3 loops
            }
        }
    }
}

if ($match_found) {
    echo "Match Found";
}
else {
    echo "Match not found";
}

Match Found
```

The two outer loops in `$i` and `$j` consider all distinct pairs of associate arrays in your outer array.  Then, for each pair, we iterate the keys of both, checking to see if any of the value pairs are the same.  I assume that all associate arrays would have the same keys.

Comment: for achieve my expected result we need to use three for loops , then what happen performance ? it will take to much time ?

Comment: Yes, for very large arrays this could take time.  But in the absence of knowing more about your data (e.g. some type of sorting), this the best I can offer to you.

Comment: suppose `$questionResult` will convert as associative array means , we can achieve this answer easily ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Maybe you should wait for other answers if this is far from what you really need.